# I dont know what these symbols in this code mean. Decimal to binary

Tags: javascript, binary, decimal

```
function dec2bin (decimal) {
var x = document.getElementById("deci").value;
if ((/[^0-9]/g.test(x)) || x == "") {
alert ("You must enter an integer decimal number!");
document.getElementById("deci").value = "";
document.getElementById("deci").focus();
return false;
}
x = parseInt(x);
var bin = x.toString(2);

var figs = "The binary representation of " + x + " is " + bin + "<br>";

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = figs;
```

This is the sample code my teacher gave us. It is a decimal to binary converter. I'm not entirely sure what some of these symbols mean. For example, the if statement. What exactly does

```
(/[^0-9]/g.test(x)) || x == "")
```

do? Also what exactly does

```
x = parseInt(x);
var bin = x.toString(2);
```

accomplish, I kind of understand but would like futher explanation .

Comment: It looks like a regular expression to me.

Comment: The first is a regular expression.

Comment: For what it's worth, this doesn't look like very good code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Agreed. 0/10 would not learn from this teacher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `/[^0-9]/g` is a regular expression that matches anything that isn't a decimal digit. So `/[^0-9]/g.test(x)` will be true if `x` contains any non-digits. `x == ""` is true if `x` is an empty string. Combining them, `(/[^0-9]/g.test(x)) || x == "")` is true if `x` is empty or contains non-digits. In other words, it's true if the input isn't a sequence of decimal digits. You can learn more about regular expressions at http://www.regular-expressions.info/
2. `x = parseInt(x);` calls the Javascript [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function, which converts a string representing an integer into an integer. BTW, you should always provide the second argument to specify the radix, as it may differ between implementations; it should usually be `x = parseInt(x, 10);` to indicate that you're parsing decimal.
3. `var bin = x.toString(2);` calls the Javascript [`Number.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) method. This converts a number to a string in the specified output radix. Radix 2 is binary.